# Get logs from Kubectl POD specifying Level (only ERROR)

Tags: logging, kubectl, log-level

I would like to know if is possible to filter logs, only showing ERROR Level

`kubectl logs -f -n the-namespace the-pod [LOG-LEVEL?]` in example `ERROR` only

I was trying with:

```
kubectl logs -f -n bci-api the-pod | awk '{ if ($3 == "ERROR") { print } }'
```

*The problem, are there some lines that are continuation of ERROR line and will be hidden!*

**Is it possible?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I expect it'd be trivial with awk but you haven't shown any [mcve] with concise, testabe sample input/expected output for us to test with, nor have you tagged the question with awk. If you do both things then I expect you'd get answers.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#logs) documentation there doesn't seem to be a way you can do this. There is a verbosity flag `-v` but that is for the level of verbosity in `kubectl` itself, not in the logs it is getting for the `pods/containers`.

Then you also have the `--stderrthreshold <SEVERITY>` option to `kubectl` as provided in [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/kubectl/) doc, but I suspect that is the same thing.

Perhaps a better way of handling this would be to set what is called a `logging architecture` for your cluster where you can control which logs the pod actually generates. (read more [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/)) In that way, fetching them from `kubectl` will be probably more desirable.

We almost always use a 3rd party centralized logging solution (like [fleuntd](https://www.fluentd.org/)), outside of k8s for this specific reason. And we simply inject a logging sidecar container to your pods which continuously dumps the logs to this central component. This is a very common design pattern.

Answer (score 1):

can use grep functionality to filter errors from the entire logs

```bash
kubectl logs -f -n bci-api the-pod | grep -i 'Error'
```

Answer (score 1):

grep wont work if message with level INFO/WARNING will contains word error

```
kubectl logs -f -n bci-api the-pod | awk '{ if ($3 ~ "ERROR") { print } }'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

in addition to the above answer of [@Be_hegade](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11724646/be-hegade) answer, if your error spreads along multiple lines, or you want to see extra content, you can use the following `grep` command flags:

```
  -B, --before-context=NUM  print NUM lines of leading context
  -A, --after-context=NUM   print NUM lines of trailing context
  -C, --context=NUM         print NUM lines of output context
  -NUM                      same as --context=NUM
```